# Error installing VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.10 x86_64

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 18.10, linux-headers

I'm kind of new in linux, and I'm having some problems trying to install  VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.10. It's having a kernel module version error, apparently the kernel version that the VB needs is not  compatible with Ubuntu's version. When I try to run the VB it shows the following message: `Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)` ([picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gYtl.png)), When I try to reinstall the kernel module by executing `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`, it shows this message ([picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38jDE.png)):

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel for adding new hardware support to the system. The distribution packages containing the headers are probably: linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic.
```

But when I try to install this 4.15 version, it says is it not compatible ([picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF5LP.png)). Anyone could please help me solve this problem?  thanks in advance.

Observations:

1. The version of VB I was trying to install was 6.0 and I followed the
   tutorial of that site
   "https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-virtualbox6-ubuntu-18-04-centos-7/".
2. [Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVbn.png), shows the options of kernel version, but I had    already try the most recent and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox needs a couple of packages to work, the kernel headers and `dkms`.
To install both, you can run:

`sudo apt install linux-headers-generic dkms`

This will probably fix your problem. If you have recently updated your OS with a new kernel and haven't restarted since then. I highly recommend you to restart your computer.
If you're still encountering errors after this. You should reinstall virtualbox, just run:

`sudo apt purge virtualbox-6.0 && sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0`

Comment: Thank you for your help Felipe, but I had already the dkms installed. Anyway, I purged the dkms and also the linux-headers-generic, then I reinstalled them with the comand you suggested, and made the same to the Virtualbox. But the error continues,  I am getting the same message that was in picture 2 of the original post, saying that I should install the 4.15 version, but the version installed with the dkmg is the 4.18 and I can't install the 4.15, because it is not compatible.

Comment: Usually, this type of errors get fixed when you restart your computer. That's because you probably are using 4.15 but have installed an updated for version 4.18 and it hasn't been loaded yet because of the restart.